# ServiceHost Class constructor

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm refering the book Microsoft Windows Communication Foundation Step By Step. It says that

> If you omit the base address
>   information in the ServiceHost
>   constructor, like this:
>
> ServiceHost productsServiceHost = new
>        ServiceHost(typeof(ProductsServiceImpl));
>
> the WCF runtime will just use the
>   address information specified in the
>   application configuration file, and
>   automatically listen for requests on
>   all configured endpoints.

But when I try to declare the ServiceHost class using VS 2010, it gives only 2 option for ServiceHost class. Both of which need base url. Is above constructor removed in VS 2010 or am  I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was missing the baseAddress element.

Answer (score 6):

There are indeed two constructors:

- [`public ServiceHost(Object singletonInstance, params Uri[] baseAddresses)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx)
- [`public ServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585489.aspx)

However, note that they both use a [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) argument for the base addresses.  This means it is valid to not pass anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But when I compile the code, it gives me an error at the constructor.

Comment: This is the exact exception I'm getting.  System.InvalidOperationException {"Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are []."} I add endpoint in the web.confog

Comment: Source code  productServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProductsServiceCS));  <service name="ProductsService.ProductsServiceCS">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:9000/ProductsService/ProductsService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="ProductsServiceHttpEndpoint"
          contract="ProductsService.IProductService" />
              <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9090/TcpProductsService"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="ProductsServiceTcpEndpoint"
          contract="ProductsService.IProductService" />
      </service>

Comment: @gmail user: It sounds like your config is missing a metadata exchange (MEX) endpoint.  MSDN has information about how to add a MEX endpoint through config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765.aspx .